# Calculator in python problems

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a calculator in python but when I run it and do for example 123 and 321 I get 123321 instead of 444, What am I doing wrong?

```
import time
print("Calculator 1.0")
print("made by AnAwesomeMiner")
print("Number 1 in calculation")
x = input()
print("Number 2")
y = input()
print("calculating")
time.sleep(3)
print("why is this not done yet")
time.sleep(3)
print("god this is taking forever")
time.sleep(3)
print("done")
answear = x + y
print(answear)
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me of my first programs from when I was eight years old. Wow. I think mine was called MaxMath and I spent most of the time printing a splash screen in Rexx...

Comment: @bur - why the tag change?

Comment: @Lix, because in python-2.x, input actually evaluates the input, so the example given would work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`input` returns a string, and when you combine two strings the result is what you are seeing.

```
>>> x = '123'
>>> y = '321'
>>> x+y
'123321'
```

So you need to convert them to an integer, like this:

```
answear = int(x) + int(y)
```

Comment: Oh i thought phyton did that by it self, is there anyway to automate this?

Comment: Its quite automatic right now; you have to know what is _supposed_ to be entered. Everything from `input` is a string, so Python cannot know if you want a number, a float, a file name, or an actual string. So its left up to you to check what the user enters and then do whatever is required of the inputs.

Answer (score 7):

`input()` returns string not number . That's why instead of addition , String concatenation is performed.

you need to use `int(x)` and `int(y)` for conversion.

use this statement `answear = int(x) + int(y)`

Comment: `input()` return number, ie `>>> y = input()`, 3, `>>> y+3`, 6

Comment: @suhail only in python 2, in python 3 it returns a string.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this :

```
y=int(input())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are declaring it as a string. Use `a = int(input())`. This will cast it into an integer. If you want to insert a decimal number use the `float` data type.

Answer (score 0):

input() accepts and returns a string object and you need to typecast this into an integer (or float) if you want to perform arithmetic operations on it. Performing a + operation on two strings merely concatenates them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of input(), use int(input()). This will tell Python that the user is about to enter an integer.

Answer (score 0):

> 

```
def main():

    def add(x,y):
        return x + y
    def sub(x,y):
        return x - y
    def mult(x,y):
        return x * y
    def div(x,y):
        return x / y
    def remainder(x,y):
        return x % y
    repeat=True
    while repeat:
        select=int(input("please select any operation:-\n 1.ADD\n2.SUBTRACT\n3.MULTIPLY\n4.DIVIDE\n5.REMAINDER\nselect here:-"))
        num1=int(input("Enter the first number"))
        num2=int(input("Enter the second number"))

        if select==1:
            print(num1,"+",num2,"=",add(num1,num2))
        elif select==2:
            print(num1,"-",num2,"=",sub(num1,num2))
        elif select==3:
            print(num1,"*",num2,"=",mult(num1,num2))
        elif select==4:
            print(num1,"/",num2,"=",div(num1,num2))
        elif select==5:
            print(num1,"%",num2,"=",remainder(num1,num2))
        else:
            print("invalid input")
        print("Do you want to calculate further?\n press y for continue.\n press any other key to terminate.")
        repeat="y" in str(input())
        if repeat=="y":
            print("Ooo yeh! you want to continue")
        else:
            print("Tnakyou")
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem to fix. When adding to integers or doing any other operation including an input and an int you need to do this:

```
y = int(input())
x = int(input())
a = y+x
```

so this put into your code looks like this:

```
import time
print("Calculator 1.0")
print("made by AnAwesomeMiner")
print("Number 1 in calculation")
x = int(input())
print("Number 2")
y = int(input())
print("calculating")
time.sleep(3)
print("why is this not done yet")
time.sleep(3)
print("god this is taking forever")
time.sleep(3)
print("done")
answear = x + y
print(answear)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def run_calculation(user_choice):

    num1, num2 = ........

    match : user_choice

        case '1':

            result = addition(num1, num2)

        case '2':

            result = substraction(num1, num2)

        case '3':

            result = multiplication(num1, num2)

        case '4':

            result = division(num1, num2)

       
........ :

            print("Choix invalide.")

    return result
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).